# How to copy closed loop lines into polygon feature class

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, polygon, polygon-creation, line

I'm trying to utilize line contour data to find the volumes of local depressions. To do this, I want to copy the closed loops formed by depression contours into a polygon feature class to find the area of the loops. I've done this several times in ArcGIS 10.0 successfully by selecting the contours I want to copy, then using "Ctrl+C" and "Ctrl+V". My organization just upgraded to 10.1 and the ability to copy from line data to polygon data doesn't seem to work. Is this ability no longer supported, or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you have the Advanced level of ArcMap you could give the Feature to Polygon tool a try?

Comment: It looks like that will work. It's not nearly as convenient though as the copy+paste process is. It adds an extra step, requires an intermediate shapefile, and doesn't seem to preserve the attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Construct Polygons on the Advanced Editing Tool, to create polygons from a single line or many lines. The attributes do not carry over. You can easily enter values in the Editor, Attributes window, or maybe perform a Spatial Join to transfer attributes when you are finished with the geometry.